# MySQL: Selecting value from 2 tables comparing

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, permissions and permissions_inheritance

Structure of permissions : http://prntscr.com/4h94cx
Structure of permissions_inheritance : http://prntscr.com/4h95gh

What I need to do is select 'administrator' as `parent` of `permissions_inheritance` and then the 'child' of those results to `name` of `permissions`

So far I have:

```
`SELECT * FROM `permissions_inheritance`, `permissions` WHERE `parent` =` 'administrator'
```

but dont know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the both tables :

```
SELECT * FROM permissions p LEFT JOIN permissions_inheritance pi ON p.child=pi.name WHERE p.parent = 'administrator';
```

Note : depending on what you need finally, maybe `LEFT JOIN` is not the more adequat answer, but without more preicision, it should do the work ;)

Comment: Worked great with some modification! Thanks!